# How to fix error "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" when 'php artisan migrate'?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to run `php artisan migrate` to create my mysql tables usin laravel.

I got this error: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Users Table:

> ```
> Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
>       $table->increments('id');
>       $table->string('name');
>       $table->string('email', 150)->unique();
>       $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
>       $table->string('password');
>       $table->rememberToken();
>       $table->timestamps();
>  });
> ```

Albums Table:

> ```
> Schema::create('albums', function (Blueprint $table) {
>        $table->increments('id');
>        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
>        $table->string('title');
>        $table->text('description');
>        $table->boolean('public');
>        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')-> 
>        onDelete('SET NULL');
>        $table->timestamps();
>    });
> ```

Images table:

> ```
> Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
>        $table->increments('image_id');
>        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();;
>        $table->string('image');
>        $table->integer('album_id')->unsigned();;
>        $table->string('title');
>        $table->string('description');
>        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')- >onDelete('SET NULL');
>        $table->foreign('album_id')->references('id')->on('albums')->onDelete('SET NULL');
>        $table->timestamps();
>    });
> ```

But have error:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `photo_storage`.`#sql-2d70_10a` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `albums` add constraint `albums_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete SET NULL)`
> ```

Comment: Can you post the migation which is creating the `photo_storage` table please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `->onDelete('SET NULL')` it expects the field user_id/album_id to be nullable.
Make `user_id` and `album_id` from images and albums tables nullable like this 
`$this->integer('field')->nullable()`
 and try again

Comment: I add `->nullable()` and it helpful. Thanks very much !!